# f:selectItems from POJO and grouping - I´ve get only String instead the POJO

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I´m trying to use the Primefaces component: p:selectOneListbox
I would like to use the **grouping** function.

Currently I´m getting only a String instead the POJO. I´m already using a converter, but I don´t know what is currently wrong. If I´m returning only the List then it´s working fine and I´ve get the values as expected...

Here is my JSF code:

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="diagramElementList" value="#{myBean.selectedDiagramElementFromList}"
                    converter="diagramElementConverter" style="width: 100%"
                    var="diagramElement" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">

                    <f:selectItems
                        value="#{availableAutomationComponentControllerView.generateListAvailableElements()}"
                        var="diagramElement" itemLabel="#{diagramElement.name}"
                        itemValue="#{diagramElement}" />

                    <p:column style="width: 10px;">

                            <h:outputText value="#{diagramElement.icon}" />

                    </p:column>
```

Here my backend bean:

```
public List<SelectItem> generateListAvailableElements() {

    try {

        List<SelectItem> list = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        SelectItemGroup g1 = new SelectItemGroup("Workflow");
        List<DiagramElement> workflowList = automationElementService.generateListAvailableElements(
                loginBean.getCurrentEmployee(), localeBean.getLanguage(),
                AutomationElementCategory.WORKFLOW.toString());
        g1.setSelectItems(createItemList(workflowList));
        list.add(g1);

        return list;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        ErrorMessage.showErrorMessage();
    }

    return null;
}


private SelectItem[] createItemList(List<DiagramElement> list) {

    List<SelectItem> newlist = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    for (DiagramElement e : list) {
        newlist.add(new SelectItem(e, e.getName()));
    }

    SelectItem[] arr = new SelectItem[newlist.size()];
    arr = newlist.toArray(arr);

    return arr;
}
```

And here my converter:

```
@FacesConverter("diagramElementConverter")
```

public class DiagramElementConverter implements Converter {

```
@Inject
private AutomationElementService automationElementService;

@Inject
private LoginBean loginBean;

@Inject
private LocaleBean localeBean;

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {

    String field = (object instanceof DiagramElement) ? ((DiagramElement) object).getId() : null;
    return (field != null) ? String.valueOf(field) : null;
}

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {

    try {
        if (submittedValue == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
        } else {
            for (DiagramElement diagramElement : automationElementService.generateListAvailableElements(
                    loginBean.getCurrentEmployee(), localeBean.getLanguage(), null)) {

                if (diagramElement.getId().equals(submittedValue)) {
                    return diagramElement;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you save your selected item? Checking in debug, the converter is called?

Comment: Yes, the converter is called... But it seems I got everytime a String and not the Object: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'icon'.

Comment: Sorry but selectOneListbox don't have value attribute (don't you need it?) and there's no reference to icon field, I'm missing something

Comment: you are right, I´ve reduced my code - I´ve added it to the code above... but this is not the issue itself...

Comment: Have you tried changing one of the var value? Could be not relate to the problem, but using the same value is not a good choice anyway

Comment: Yes, I did - but it´s not working

Comment: I don't understand what is the `grouping function` . More over if you are using omnifaces try to http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsIndexConverter

Comment: Please see here "grouping" https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

Comment: Your selectItems is a list of List<SelectItem> so diagramElement.icon can't work. You have to modify DiagramElement to extends SelectItem or redesign your flow/page/logic(eg. can't you create that list just once, on page load?)

Comment: What do you mean with "flow / page / logic" ? Btw. is it fine to have this code:  <f:selectItems value="#{availableAutomationComponentControllerView.generateListAvailableElements()}" or should this be @PostConstruct and then have <f:selectItems value="#{availableAutomationComponentControllerView.listElements}" ?

Comment: I mean that you have to recheck your logic, if you convert from your bean to a SelectItem, you can't use your bean fields (check omnifaces converter or  make your bean implements SelectItem). For the other point, I prefer one call on @PostConstruct, so if you update that component you don't need to recreate that list.